# Can I turn a can of red kidney beans into red bean paste for Japanese Style Red Bean Paste Buns?

Tags: beans, japanese-cuisine

I have a can of Red Kidney Beans, and I want to use it to make Japanese Red Bean Paste Buns. Looking online, I found that these buns require Azuki Beans for the paste, not Kidney Beans. Is there a way to turn Kidney Beans into a replacement for Azuki Beans?

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27495/azuki-bean-substitute-for-anpan/27496#27496

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Welcome. According to the excerpt below from  [this page](http://www.foodsubs.com/Beans.html) , kidney beans are an acceptable substitute.

> azuki bean = adzuki bean = Tiensin red bean = aduki bean = asuki bean = field pea = red Oriental bean = feijao bean = red chori    Equivalents: 1 cup dried yields 3 cups cooked beans  Pronunciation:  a-ZOO-kee   Notes:   The Japanese use these small red beans to make sweet red bean paste, but they're also good in rice dishes or salads.  Azuki beans are sweet and relatively easy to digest, so they won't make you as gassy as other beans.  They also don't take as long to cook.   Substitutes:   black azuki beans OR red kidney beans OR Tolosana beans

That said, while you may be able to substitute them you may need to make adjustments to end up with a similar bean paste. For example you may need to add more sugar as adzuki beans have a natural slightly sweet flavor.

Also, even though you have canned beans, they may require a bit of cooking to get them to the right softness. (Adzuki beans tend to have a very creamy texture.) Note that dark red kidney beans tend to be more firm than light red.

All said and done, you can probably make adjustments and end up with a slightly different result. But as for me, I would get the adzuki beans.

Comment: I'd be interested to know how good of a substitute that is; in that context, it might just be a "here's as close as you'll get without the real thing" substitute.

Comment: I'd also suggest pureeing the kidney beans - in many cases kidney beans have a shell/skin that won't be pleasing if you just mash the beans down. The idea of adding some sugar to get the taste right also makes sense to me. But you'd want a comparison azuki bean to get the flavor right. But if you have a comparison, why not just use it, instead of the kidney bean?

Comment: @SteveMidgley The point is for us to tell the OP whether it'll work, not make the OP do the experiment himself.

Answer (score 8):

No, azuki beans are very different in texture and flavor from kidney beans, you won't be able to use them as a substitute.

Comment: I think it would require a lot of trial and error to get the sweetness right. Better to buy them from a Japanese market, but if you don't have one nearby online should be OK, as you can get them canned or as raw beans.

Comment: who is going to stop them

Comment: I will @c.. I'll find them wherever they are.